# Nuxt Nested link causes images 404

Tags: image, routes, nested, http-status-code-404, nuxt.js

I am having issues loading my images on my Nuxt Universal app.

Here is my pages structure

```
├── travelers
│   ├── _id.vue
│   └── index.vue
│── about
│── index
```

If I load

- **localhost:3000/**
- **localhost:3000/about**
- **localhost:3000/travelers**

everything works fine.

But if I load

- **localhost:3000/travelers/4**
- **localhost:3000/travelers/**
- **localhost:3000/about/**

I get a 404 on all my images.

I checked the images links on the pages where it doesn't work, it seems their link is changing depending on the page. So, instead of my initial call which was `<img src="svg/logo.svg">` I am getting `<img src="about/svg/logo.svg">`

I couldn't find an answer to my issue.

Comment: Please share the template code for one of your images that isn’t working, so we can see the src attribute.

Comment: I did, it's simply `<img src="svg/logo.svg">`

Comment: Are your images in your static folder or assets folder?

Comment: they are on my static folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re missing a leading `/` in your `img src`. For example, if you have `logo.svg` inside a folder called `images` inside your `static` directory, the correct `src` is:

```
<img src=“/images/logo.svg/>
```

Without the leading /, your paths are **relative** to the **page**, not the `static` directory of your application.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, works great. I have one more question, is it better to put my images on the static folder or assets one ?

Comment: If you put them in your assets folder, they may be optimised as part of your production build process. Smaller file sizes are generally a good thing. However, as part of the build process the file names will be altered which means visitors who have already downloaded the img once, will have to download it again each time you build your app for production. If you store images in your static folder, they are not optimised for you but the file names rename the same— so visitors can rely on their browsers cache to prevent them from downloading images unnecessarily.

Comment: As a general rule I optimise images myself and store them in the static directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in **Nuxt JS version 3.0**. it require to write **static** path like this,

```
<img src="@/static/img/hamburg.png" />
```

and for **:src** issue you can write like this,

```
<img :src="@/static/img/hamburg.png" />
```

or this if it is a **JSON data array property** (Example, for each $destination in $destinations),

```
 <img :src="`_nuxt/static/img/${destination.image}`"/>
```